# $X,Y,Z $ s.t. $E[X | Y ] = E[X | Z ] \implies E[X | Y ] = E[X | Z ] = E[X | Y,Z ]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Is it true that :

$ \forall X,Y,Z $  $$E[X | Y ] = E[X | Z ]  \implies E[X | Y ]  = E[X | Z ]  = E[X | Y,Z ]$$

I tried to find $X,Y,Z$ with X not independant of $Y,Z$ and $$E[X | Y ]  = E[X | Z ]  = E[X]$$
but without success.

Has anyone a counter example for that ? It seems blatantly false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false. Let $Y,Z \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{2})$ be independent and $X=\begin{cases}0 & Y=Z \\ 1 & Y \neq Z \end{cases}$. Notice that $X\sim \text{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{2})$ as well, $X$ is independent of $Y$, $X$ is independent of $Z$, but $X,Y,$ and $Z$ are not mutually independent. In fact, $X$ is measurable with respect to the sigma algebra generated by $Y$ and $Z$. So we have:
$$E[X\mid Y] = E[X\mid Z] = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$E[X \mid Y,Z] =X.$$

Comment: really visual example, cheers

Answer (score 2):

$$Y:=|X|, Z:=X^2, X\sim N(0,1) \implies E[X\mid Y]=E[X\mid Z]=E[X]$$ 
Then they are obviously not independent. The issue is, that once you start to package information about the sign into either Y or Z in order to get something different for $E[X\mid Y,Z]$ you run into issues, since that moves the expected value above or below zero. So you need to somehow fix that.

---

So what about this: 
$$\begin{align}
&Z\sim U\{-1,1\} \perp X\sim N(0,1), Y=Z\cdot X\\
\implies& E[X\mid Z]=E[X]
\end{align}$$
And since $X=Z^2 X = Z Y$ we get 
$$E[X\mid Y]=E[ZY\mid Y]=YE[Z\mid Y]=0=E[X]$$

---

Lastly if we also want Z and X be dependent, we could do something like:
$$U\sim U\{-1,1\} \perp X\sim N(0,1)$$
Let
$$Y:=UX$$
and
$$
Z=\begin{cases}
|X| & U=1\\
|X|+1 & U=-1
\end{cases}
$$
Then neither none of the variables are independent, but:
$$E[X\mid Y]=0=E[X \mid Z]=E[X]$$
And
$$E[X\mid Z,Y]=X $$

Comment: how did you come up with those example, they look really complicated?

Comment: @MarineGalantin that is why I left the first bit there. The first example with the $|\cdot|$ is well known. Then I tried to modify it such that you get something else for $E[X\mid Y,Z]$. But as I said, you need the information about the sign in one of the variables. So I tried doing that by making the sign random and storing that in one of the variables (second example). But then one variable was completely independent. So I tried to make them both dependent on X while keeping the property of the conditional expectations.

Comment: I see, cheers ! I gave the good answer to the other answer because it is really really straightforward, but thanks a bunch for your answer.